# Descobrir evento executado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz o seguinte comando para exibir um loading sempre que fizer um submit dos forms do projeto.

```
$("button[data-noPreload!='true'][type='submit']").click(openPreloading);
function openPreloading() {
    $("#icoCarregando").fadeIn();
}
```

Encontrei este outro código para ajudar a corrigir uma falha para fechar a tela de loading quando houver erros no preenchimento do formulário.

```
$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
    $("#icoCarregando").hide();
});
```

Até aqui tudo estava funcionando bem, o problema cujo estou precisando de ajuda é quando o usuário da um **duplo clique** para salvar um formulário cujo com erro, o evento criado acima parece não surtir efeito, assim abrindo a tela de Loading, ao debugar consegui identificar que as funções criadas acima estão sendo executadas porém parece esta executado algum evento a mais onde carrega o loading.

Existe alguma forma de identificar qual evento pode estar sendo executado e causando esse problema? Ou sabe como posso estar contornando essa falha?

Agradeço a atenção!

Comment: `C#` é realmente a _tag dominante_ para essa questão? 

Comment: @LuizFelipe, tag removida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será que não está abrindo duas vezes o ícone carregando com o duplo clique?

Tenta alterar as tuas funções para essa forma:

```
var carregando = false;
$("button[data-noPreload!='true'][type='submit']").click(openPreloading);
function openPreloading() {
    if(carregando === false){
        $("#icoCarregando").fadeIn();
        carregando = true;
    }
}

$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
    $("#icoCarregando").hide();
    carregando = false;
});
```

Comment: Conseguiria fazer um exemplo do teu código funcionando para que possamos analisar melhor?

Comment: Refiz o teste conforme você passou! Funcionou perfeitamente! Agradeço muito a ajuda!